# How do you compute elapsed time for KEYDOWN. (Python)

Tags: python, pygame, elapsedtime

I am wondering how to increase a variable if a key is held down for longer. I am using Python and PyGame. 
This is a sample of my code (speed, lap, and distance are defined in previous lines):

```
distance_control = 1
for i in range(amount):
    x[i] += speedx[i]
    if x[i] >= 800:
        x[i] -= 800
        lap[i] += 1
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            x[2] += 1
    distance[i] = (lap[i] - 1)*800 + x[i]
```

I was wondering how to make it so that the longer you hold down the Space Bar, the higher the speed_control goes, and the max speed_control is 5, preferably using some sort of elapsed time thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) function which returns the time since the program start to compute the elapsed time. Set the `start_time` to the current time in the event loop when the user presses the key and in the while loop you can check if it is still held down with [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) and compute the elapsed time.

```
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((320, 240))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    start_time = 0

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    start_time = pg.time.get_ticks()

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:  # The spacebar is held.
            current_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
            elapsed_time = current_time-start_time  # milliseconds
            print(elapsed_time)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

---

If you just want to count the frames:

```
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((320, 240))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    counter = 0

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    counter = 0 # Set it back to 0.

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:  # The spacebar is held.
            # Increment the counter every frame.
            counter += 1
            print(counter)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: thank you for this. How would one be able to add one to a variable every one thousand milliseconds, as when I test the program by holding down space, I notice the numbers are skipping some

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: trying to add acceleration for a car the longer you hold spacebar down

Comment: I think you should post another question, something like "How can I accelerate an object?". And add a short description of your goals and a code example to show us what you've tried.

Comment: I've already got an answer, you just have to post the question. ;) Do you know how vectors and pygame sprites work? Write a comment with @skrx to send me a notification.